# looking back in time for first green bar

Tags: pine-script, trading

I am playing with some code (very new to Pine) where I look for 3 green candles in a row and add a label to that first candle. That part is easy enough with bar_index-2.
However, let's say there are 5 green candles in a row. I get multiple labels but I only want the label to be on that first green candle that started the 5 in a row. How do I get that info?
thanks for your help!
Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requires a down bar to reset the condition:

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)

// Define our boolean condition for an up bar.
upBar = close > open

// Here we do many things in one line:
// 1. Using `sum()`, we will add a value for the last 3 bars.
//    That's the `sum(..., 3)` part.
// 2. The value we add for each bar is the evaluation of an expression.
//    That expression is a ternary: `upBar ? 1 : 0`.
//    It evaluates to `1` if the current bar is an upBar,
//    and to zero when it is not.
// 3. We use the `==` boolean operator to compare the result of `sum()` to `3`.
//    When it is equal to `3`, `true` will be assigned to `upBars3`.
//    This will occur when `upBar` was true on each of the last 3 bars.
upBars3 = sum(upBar ? 1 : 0, 3) == 3

// Here we generate a signal when our `upBars3` boolean variable is `true`,
// and it was not `true` on the previous bar, which is the `not upBars3[1]` part.
signal = upBars3 and not upBars3[1]

// Here we plot an arrow 2 bars back when our signal triggers.
// Note that if you publish a script plotting in the past like this,
// it is expected that you will explain this in your script's description
// so you do not mislead traders into thinking your script is prescient.
plotchar(signal, "signal", "▲", location.top, size = size.tiny, offset = - 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that!!  
Can you describe what the sum(upBar ? 1 : 0, 3) == 3 does?  
  
I read it as :  
If upBar is true then set value to 1 otherwise 0.

Comment: There are sums in there and some kind of test to see if it's 3 but I don't understand the syntax and I want to understand it. i didn't see this in the "language operators" section of the manual regarding the , specifically. Thank you!

Comment: There is indeed a lot going on in those few lines. I added comments to the code. If I may say so, those lines are also an eloquent illustration of the power of Pine. Feel free if you have questions.